# AS3 | C# - How to use path with button

Tags: c#, visual-studio, actionscript-3, flash

So I have a variable located in this path folder here (From JPEX):
root|DT2.swf|scripts|com|wdf|doodletoo|ToolController

Here's a image from JPEX. https://i.gyazo.com/6487c9306aeee94dbcc8d16c9afb904b.png.

As you can see the variable is in some folders. So doing it like this doesn't work because of that: `(_root.size, "999999")`

Like he does in this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9nH0Vfq1OxE&t=454s.

this is how he did his in the video above.

`(_root.maxspeed, 999999)`

I noticed the variable `maxspeed` isn't in some folders though like mine.
The variable I need to change is in some folders. Here is the path to the variable. `root|DT2.swf|scripts|com|wdf|doodletoo|ToolController`

In the path above. You can see `scripts` and `com` these are folders.

How could I use that path above to change a variable's value with a button?

I've tried removing the "|" and replacing it with "_" hoping it would work but no luck.

I just need to pretty much define the path to the variable, but the folders are making it a hectic problem for me.

```
 Game.SetVariable("_root_DT2.swf_scripts_com_wdf_doodletoo_ToolController_size", "999999");
```

The Variable's name I'm trying to change the value of is named "size"

Comment: Other implications aside, a) you cannot just change a variable inside Flash app unless specifically provided so from inside of the app with **ExternalInterface** class, also b) the variable you are trying to access/change is a class member and is not attached to **root** anyway.

Comment: So it's pretty much impossble?

Comment: I won't say "impossible", but you should learn really a lot to understand how Flash Player works, what SWF-format is, what ABC-code is, and so on. Simply, in order to pull off that hack you want, you need to have a much higher level of understanding, than you need to script such an application (and then you can provide any access from the outside you want) yourself.